# Python - accessing variable that is needed for function defined in different moduel

Tags: python

I have saved a defined function within a module, which I have then imported into a new script.

Within this function, the variable `master` (a pandas dataframe) is queried. However, `master` is not one of the arguments in the function and is a dataframe I am hoping to access regardless of the script.

When trying to use the aforementioned function in my new script, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'master' is not defined
```

But when I enter `master` into the console, it prints with no problem or error.

I think it is something to do with local and global variables, but I am new to Python and am struggling to understand how I can fix the error.

Comment: If you only read from 'master' it has to be accessible already. But if you modifying it, it has to be accessed as global variable via 'global master' declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Within this function, the variable master (a pandas dataframe) is queried. However, master is not one of the arguments in the function

Then update your function to take it as an argument. You can't use a global here, since (if I understand correctly), your "master" variable is defined in your script and the function in a module that's imported by the script. In this case explicitely passing "master" to your function is the only way to make it available since Python has no true "global" namespace ("global" in Python actually means "module level").

And that's a GoodThing actually because it's the only sane way to structure your program.  As a general rule, globals (mutable globals that is) are evil, they make your code brittle, untestable, unmaintainable and unpredictable.